# Having problems setting a delete route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Took me a while but finally was able to have a `user_id` and `friend_id` associate with each other through friendships model. The problem I'm having is:

**When clicking "add friend"**

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
 <% if user.user_name != current_user.user_name %>
  <% if @friendshiplink.nil? %>
   <%= user.user_name %>
   <%= link_to "Add Friend", friendships_path(friend_id: user.id), method: :post %>
  <% else %>
   <%= link_to(
       ("Unfollow"),
      "/friendships/#{ @friendship.id }",
      method: :delete ) %>
  <% end %>
 <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

I get in respond is:

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #86):

 <% else %>
  <%= link_to(
         ("Unfollow"),
         "/friendships/#{ @friendship.id }",
         method: :delete ) %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Please let me know if I'm missing any code in order to further understand what might be the issue

**Rake Routes**

```
friendships POST   /friendships(.:format)       friendships#create
friendship DELETE /friendships/:id(.:format)   friendships#destroy
```

**Friendship Controller**

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController
 def create
  # @friendship = current_user.friendships.build
  # @friendship.friend_id = params[:friend_id]
  # @friendship.user_id = current_user.id
  @friendship = current_user.friendships.build(friend_id: params[:friend_id])
  if @friendship.save
   flash[:notice] = "Added friend."
   redirect_to "/users/#{ params[:friend_id] }"
  else
   flash[:notice] = "Unable to add friend"
   redirect_to root_url
  end
 end

 def destroy
  @friendship = current_user.friendships.find(params[:id])
  @friendship.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "Removed friendship."
  redirect_to current_user
 end

 private

 def friendship_params
  params.require(:friendship).permit(:user_id, :friend_id)
 end
end
```

**User Controller**

```
def index
 @user = User.new
 @users = User.all

 if current_user
  @leaders = @current_user.leaders
 end
end

def create
 @user = User.new(user_params)
 if @user.save
  session[:user_id] = @user.id
  cookies[:user_id] = @user.id
  flash[:notice] = "Successfully Registerd"
  redirect_to "/"
 else
  flash[:alert] = @user.errors.full_messages
  redirect_to "/"
 end
end

def new
 @user = User.new
end

def edit
 @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
 current_user
end

def show
 @users = User.all
 @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
 current_user
 if @current_user
  @followerlink = Follower.where(leader_id: @user.id,
                                 follower_id: @current_user.id).first
  @friendshiplink = Friendship.where(friend_id: @user.id,
                                     user_id: @current_user.id).first
 end
end

def update
 @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
 if @user.update(user_params)
  flash[:notice] = "You have successfully update your information"
  redirect_to "/"
 else
  flash[:alert] = @user.errors.full_messages
  redirect_to "/"
 end
end

def destroy
 @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
 @user.destroy
end

private

def user_params
 params.require(:user).permit(:background, :username_or_email, :first_name,  :last_name, :email, :password, :user_name, :avatar, :gender, :zip_code,  :birthdate)
end
```

**Where code is in user/view**

```
<div id="user_profile">
 <div id="profile_top">
  <a href="/"><p class="profile_logo"></p></a>
  <nav>
  <div class="profile_loginout">
    <%= link_to ("LOGOUT"), "/sessions/new",method: :delete %>
  </div>
  <div class="profile_user-links">
   <a href="/users/<%= current_user.id %>">
    <% if current_user.user_name.present? %>
     <%= link_to current_user.user_name, user_path(current_user) %>
    <% else %>
     <%= current_user.first_name %>
    <% end %>
   </a>
   &nbsp;<b class="size">|</b>&nbsp;
   <a href="">Settings</a>
   &nbsp;<b class="size">|</b>&nbsp;
  </div>
 </nav>
</div> 

<div id="profile_to">
 <div class="profile_background_picture">
  <%= image_tag @user.background.url(:medium) %>
 </div>
 <div class="profile_picture">
  <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:medium) %>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
<% if @current_user && @user.id != @current_user.id %>
 <% if !@followerlink %>
  <form action="/followers" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden"
      name="authenticity_token"
      value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>">
   <input type="hidden"
      name="leader_id"
      value=<%= @user.id %>>
   <input type="submit" value="Follow" class="followlink">
  </form>
 <% else %>
  <div class="followlink">
   <%= link_to(
       ("Unfollow"),
        "/followers/#{ @followerlink.id }",
          method: :delete ) %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
<% end %>


<p>Username: <%= @user.user_name %></p>

<h2>Friends</h2> 
<ul>
 <% for friendship in @user.friendships %>
  <li>
   (<%= link_to "remove", friendship, method: :delete %>)
  </li>
 <% end %>
</ul>

<p><%= link_to "Find Friends", users_path %></p>

<h2> Users who Have Befriended you </h2>
<ul>
 <% for user in @user.inverse_friends %>
  <li> <%= h user.user_name %></li>
 <% end %>
</ul>

<% @users.each do |user| %>
 <% if user.user_name != current_user.user_name %>
  <% if @friendshiplink.nil? %>
   <%= user.user_name %>
   <%= link_to "Add Friend", friendships_path(friend_id: user.id), method:     :post  %>
  <% else %>
   <%= link_to "Unfollow", friendships_unfollow_path(@friendship), method: :delete %>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Thank you for all the help or hints in solving the issue. Greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What's the name of the template where `"/friendships/#{ @friendship.id }"` is placed?

Comment: @dimakura are you referring to routes? The link I was trying to make for the  "unfollow" a user was from rake routes of friendships. If I misunderstood, where can I have the templates?

Answer (score 1):

On top of my head, not sure it's working but try it...

In routes:

```
delete '/friendships/:id', to: 'friendships_controller#destroy', as: 'friendships_unfollow'
```

In view:

```
<%= link_to "Unfollow", friendships_unfollow_path(@friendship), method: :delete %>
```

It is unclear where do you get your @friendship variable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've added what you recommended except did 'friendships#destroy since with controller it brought an error. I'm able to unfollow a user except when I click add I get a route error of No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"friendships", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id] and says the error is with the <%= link_to "Unfollow", friendships_unfollow_path(@ friendship), method: :delete %>. The @ friendship variable I'm getting from my friendship controller. Have I made an error there? If you want me to show more codes please tellme which

Comment: What's the name of the view of 'add_friend' and 'unfollow' part and show me a method in the controller that render that view.

Comment: I added full view of my User Controller and also the User/view where the code is being used. I was trying to use the add of a user similar to when you follow a user. I thought I was following similar method for it to work in view.